# How to block someone’s device from doing something on my site for a specific amount of time?

Tags: php, laravel

I’m working on some kind of “upvoting” system, where users can upvote a post without needing to log in.

The current logic:

1. 1 upvote per day from specific ip
2. One upvote per day from specific MAC Address (1 and 2 combined)

But: on ios / android / pc if you just switch to 4G and do “airplane” mode where you get instantly a new IP, the mac address also gets changed, thus the users can re-upvote again countless of times!

Is there a way/logic to stop visitors from the same device to upvote again within 24 hours? Even if they change mac address or ip address.

(Using laravel)

Comment: This is far too broad for SO, but I think the topic you're looking for is "device fingerprinting".

Comment: But since users don’t need to login: does device fingerprinting work for just clicking a upvote button? And what if they don’t have “face id” or finger scanner like iphone 6. Or what if they use desktop which doesn’t have both?

Comment: You would need to collect multiple pieces of data to fingerprint your end user (IP, browser, screen resolution, timezone etc.) and even then it is not guaranteed to be complete. Also consider implications of things like [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) for an EU visitors.

Comment: A web application cannot detect the MAC address

Comment: I saw an API called fingerprint.js which offers what i ask, but they ask $200 a month for 10K visitors. If they have it, there should be a cheaper / free one?

Comment: There are free fingerprint libraries out there. I use one for my angularjs app. If you are THAT concerned with shifty cheaters, make your voting account based. Now you can check by USERID.

Comment: You can set a cookie after the upvote. A combination of cookies and IP address verification is not 100% safe but safe enough for most users. As long as you don't have an account obligation there is always a way to vote multiple times.